# Reference cell has weeknum() in it and is causing error in formula in different cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula `=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A2:A,'Initiated'!$A$1:$BA, MATCH(E2:E,'Initiated '!$A$1:$BA$1,0),0)))`

The values in 'E' cells of the E2:E part of the formula have a weeknum() formula in it.  The error I get is Did not find value '2' in MATCH evaluation.  If I take out the weeknum() formula from those cells and replace them with numbers, the formula works with no errors.  How can I make the formula work with using numweek() ?

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LQQrZcM_iQ0wNqQXgBqWnkwz-KsvmHTTku-b7DF9lzY/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be having an issue with the numbers being treated as strings, or vice versa. Instead of just `weeknum(...)`, try `weeknum(...)&""` to force conversion to string.

Or on the data `weeknum` is matching against, you can add `+0` to force conversion to number.

Or, have you double-checked that `weeknum` is returning the same number that you are hardcoding? `weeknum` takes a second parameter indicating what day of the week the week starts on if you need to tweak it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  I tried those but it still isn't working.  I added a sample sheet in the original question to give an example.

Comment: It does work, your headers in Sheet2 are strings. Change cell C3 in Sheet1 to `weeknum(B3)&""` or change your headers from `1` to `=1+0` etc.

Comment: Actually `=1+0` is redundant, obviously, you can just write `=1`, but to see the string conversion you can write `="1"+0`. In Excel there is an option to convert "Numbers stored as text" to numbers, but I'm not seeing that in Sheets. If your headers are fixed and you can't change them for whatever reason, you can change your big formula to `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$AA, MATCH(C2,ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1+0),0),0)`. The `VALUE` function also does the same as adding `+0`.